# list index out of range while writing a program to delete duplicate elements

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to delete duplicate elements, but it shows list index out of range error at l=n[i]

```
n=list(input().split())

for i in range(len(n)):
    l=n[i]
    for j in range(len(n)):
        if(j!=i):
            if(l==n[j]):
                n.pop(j)

print(n)
```

Comment: This seems like the perfect use case for a set.

Comment: you don't need to specify that n is a list as .split() will turn it into one

Answer (score 2):

It shows error because you `pop` elements from inside, which has changed the size of list while iterating. But the `range` function is still having the original length and thus gives an index which is no longer existing.

You should **never** change the length of a list (or `keys` of a dictionary) while iterating over it.

In detail, let's take your list `n=[1,1,2,3]` (say). `i` will run in `range(3)`(i.e. take values `0,1,2,3`)

Now, `l=n[0], i.e. l=1`. Then at `j=1, n[j]=1`, the condition `l==n[j]` turns `true` and you do `n.pop(1)`.

So now, your list `n=[1,2,3]` BUT your outermost loop is still in `range(4)` and thus will give error when you do `l=n[3]` since `n[3]` doesn't exist.

To avoid this, you've following options:

1. Push the non-duplicate elements into a new list. (Or alternatively, make a copy of the original list and pop from there).
2. Use a `set` on the `list`, if you are allowed to use it.

Also, side note: `list(input().split())` is redundant call to the `list` constructor. `.split()` method returns a `list` by default.
So just `n=input().split()` is enough.